# Rbias for Vref for ADC

Tags: adc, voltage-reference

Hi guys I want to verify some calculation. 
I want to use a [Voltage Reference](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADR5040_5041_5043_5044_5045.pdf) for the 
[ADC (ATmega2560)](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf). In the datasheet(on page 11) for the voltage reference is the formula`Vbias=(Vcc-Vref)/(Iin+Iload)`. I found in the datasheet for the ADC that the ATmega2560 (page 395) uses 175uA by 5V so the resistor should be between

`Rbias = (5-4.096)/(175*10^(-6)+50*10^(-6)) = 4017.78` and 
`Rbias = (5-4.096)/(175*10^(-6)+15*10^(-3)) = 59.58`

is this right?

Comment: No.  It clearly can't be right just from a basic units check without even looking at the formulas.  This is something basic and obvious you really should have done before asking others to look at it.

Comment: That 175 uA you found is under the section *Current Consumption of Peripheral Units* which means just that **Current consumption**. It has **nothing** to do with the reference for the ADC. What resistor are you talking about anyway ? Your formula looks "made up" to me, but please prove me wrong and explain the origin of this calculation.

Comment: > It clearly can't be right. It looks reasonable to me. I think s/he is powering the AVREF pin from the voltage reference (4.096v). The datasheet suggests 175ua (per the OP) and the reference itself sinks 50ua so Rbias has to supply a minimum of 225ua, from a voltage drop of 5v-4.096v -> that's what the OP's formula is doing. 1v/225ua = 4k. put a capacitor there would be helpful as the current consumption is dynamic.

Comment: And where does it say that the AVREF pin is drawing that 175 uA ? That 175 uA is flowing through a supply ppin, like VDD. The calculation makes sense if AVREF was pulling 175 uA, which it isn't doing. And you'd lower the voltage on AVREF so if it was drawing current there (which it isn't, at least not > 100uA) then the current would not be 175 uA anymore because you lowered the voltage with the resistor. Still not convinced.

Comment: here is the formula and image form the datasheet of the Voltage Regulator
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7gP8.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxbv4.png

Comment: @Danny: Then look again.  Note the dimensionless quantity being equated to a resistance.  When the units are wrong, nothing else matters.  No answer should have been written until this fundamental issue was fixed.

Comment: Sure. The work is less than perfect, it is sloppy. But. It fundamentally makes sense. And as others pointed out, it obviously follows the datasheetss suggestion in calculating the resistance. So it is not obvious to me that that it is clearly wrong. If anything, it IS clear to me that it is fundamentally correct.

Answer (score -1):

The subject of Vrefs is a long one. There are layout considerations, noise, the possibility of considering an opamp buffer, etc. But assuming this is the circuit of choice for you and nothing is to be added (the datasheet says it is designed to work even without a capacitor across it), then what you've written out is what the calculation says to do, assuming the minimum and maximum operating currents for the ref are \$50\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ and \$15\:\textrm{mA}\$. (I saw the latter figure on page 11, so I'll assume you found the earlier one elsewhere.)

You may want to think about self-heating and the effect of that plus ambient temperature ranges on the reference voltage, minimum and maximum current draw from the ATmega device and how stable that draw is (does it vary a lot or does it just sit still, well?), and a host of other things like how stable you need the Vref.

But for a shunt regulator I think the basic rule is that you should make sure that your driving current is many times larger than your ATmega load current. Perhaps 10 times as much or more? So without digging into the datasheet further, I'd say that your minimum current to plug into the divisor would be \$2\:\textrm{mA}\$ and perhaps some more.

There's another minor problem. The difference between \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ and \$4.096\:\textrm{V}\$ isn't much to work with, so any resistor there will make for a very poor quality current source into the device. I'm not so worried about the Vref itself (it should behave well) but I am concerned about using the \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ rail here. \$\frac{\textrm{d}I}{\textrm{d}V}=\frac{1}{R}\$ and the smaller the resistor, the larger that becomes. The spec, "**OUTPUT VOLTAGE CHANGE vs.** \$I_{IN}\$" may need to be applied, along with some idea about your rail supply variations to make sure you can accept the results here.

---

I see that the \$V_{REF}\$ input resistance is spec'd to be typically \$32\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ with no minimum or maximum specified (page 365.) I guess this is where you get your \$175\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ from (\$\frac{4.096\:\textrm{V}}{32\:\textrm{k}\Omega}=128\:\mu\textrm{A}\$.)

Comment: tnx for your reaction. i got the 175μA from Figure 32-42.
AREF External Reference Current vs. VCC. At 5V it is around 175μA. I can also use a 24V rail but i think that is a bit high or a non regulated 4s lipo battery (12.8V-16.8V) what I think is even worse. Or is there a better Voltage Reference to use?

Comment: > (I saw the latter figure on page 11, so I'll assume you found the earlier one elsewhere.) the 50ua figure is the maximum value for the minimum current spec. meaning that the chip can work at a lower current level but not guaranteed to do so. 4K is a reasonable value but I would pick a 1K resistor for some head room.